# ¿Cómo establecer un parámetro con un valor por defecto en un método en Java?

Tags: java

En la siguiente función, ¿cómo puedo establecer por defecto que el valor de boolean *leerNumero* sea falso en caso de que el usuario no lo escriba cuando invoca a la función?

```
public static int numero(String texto, boolean leerNumero = false)
```

El usuario escribe:

```
numero("Numero: ");
```

Comment: no estoy muy seguro que sepas quien es tu usuario.

Comment: Creo que esto mismo se trataba en este hilo https://stackoverflow.com/questions/997482/does-java-support-default-parameter-values Un saludo!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En java no existe eso de los valores por defecto a la hora de llamar a un método. Si tu método necesita dos parámetros, has de pasárselos.

Lo que si puedes hacer es usar la sobrecarga de métodos para hacer algo similar:

```java
public static int numero(String texto, boolean leerNumero){
    //logica aqui
    return loquesea;
}

public static int numero(String texto){
    // Java sabrá automagicamente a qué metodo llamar en función de los parámetros
    // así que solo tenemos que llamar al método completo, pasándole nosotros el false
    return numero(texto, false);
}
```

---

Puedes tener infinitos métodos con el mismo nombre siempre y cuando los parámetros sean diferentes.

**Mucho ojo** con esto, porque en realidad para java estos dos métodos son iguales y darán error:

```java
public String sumaString(String unString, String otroString){
    return unString+ otroString;
}

//Esto va a dar error porque en realidad la "firma" de ambos métodos es igual: 
// String sumaString(String, String);
public String sumaString(String unString, String soyUnStringPeroTengoUnNumero){
    return unString + soyUnStringPeroTengoUnNumero;
}
```

Dicho esto, mientras tus métodos reciban diferente número de parámetros o parámetros de diferentes tipos, estará bien!